# Does digitizing a reel of (analog) Super 8 film at 1080p result in a lower *perceived* resolution/sharpness because of the said medium's film grain?

Tags: digitisation

I've read online--though I forget the exact source--that when one wants to digitize a reel of Super 8 film and create a computer video file out of it at a resolution of 1080p that the final video file looks more like a 720p video file than it does as a 1080p video file because of the film grain that's present on the Super 8 film. Is this correct?

Edit: To further clarify, I've read that when a display, say a 1080p display is fed 720p content, the display will upscale the 720p content, which will soften the image. I'm wondering if something similar happens when Super 8 film is digitized at 1080p because of the inherent nature of the medium, where a 1080p video file will look similar to a 720p video because of the film grain. Or am I conflating both the concepts of sharpness with individual pixel clarity?